# When can the commutator of two matrices be neglected in series expansions?

Tags: matrices, approximation

Under what conditions can the higher order commutators in the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula be neglected when the commutators does not vanish exactly and there is no small parameter in the matrices? Is it when the determinant of the commutator is negligible for example?